# How can I initialize a gensim LDA topic model?

Tags: python, gensim, topic-modeling

It has been suggested that initializing a topic model using clusters of words can lead to higher quality models or more robust (consistent) inference. I am talking about initializing the optimizer, not setting a prior. Here is some code to illustrate what I want to do:

Create an LdaModel object, but don't pass in a corpus.

```
lda_model =
LdaModel(
         id2word=id2word,
         num_topics=30,
         eval_every=10,
         pass=40,
         iterations=5000)
```

Next assign some property of the object, corresponding to the probabilities of drawing each word from a topic to a matrix of my own construction.

```
lda_model.topics = my_topic_mat
```

Then fit the corpus:

```
lda_model.update(corpus)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It appears that the right thing to modify might be lda_model.state.sstats

Comment: It is possible to initialize an `LdaModel` without passing a corpus, and call update later, [see docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html). Does it not work for you?

Comment: Yes it is possible to create the object without passing a corpus. I would like to initialize the topics to a certain state. I am trying to use the lda_model.state.sstats for this, but doing this doesn't seem supported.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, setting a prior may be a better choice than initializing the optimizer.

There are two hyperparameters `alpha` and `eta`, where `alpha` is a
prior for the document-topic matrix and `eta` is a prior for the
topic-word matrix. To influence word probabilities in topics, try
passing `eta` as an additional argument:

```
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(num_topics=30, id2word=id2word, eta=your_topic_mat, 
                                            eval_every=10, iterations=5000)
```

From the [gensim
docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html):

> eta can be a scalar for a symmetric prior over topic/word
>   distributions, or a vector of shape num_words, which can be used to
>   impose (user defined) asymmetric priors over the word distribution. It
>   also supports the special value ‘auto’, which learns an asymmetric
>   prior over words directly from your data. eta can also be a matrix of
>   shape num_topics x num_words, which can be used to impose asymmetric
>   priors over the word distribution on a per-topic basis (can not be
>   learned from data).

Comment: I do not want to set the prior. I want to initialize the optimizer.

Comment: @groceryheist Sorry the answer is not helpful to you. Since you asked "how to initialize a gensim LDA topic model", I thought this might be a valid answer. There was nothing about initializing an optimizer in your original post. Out of interest, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Gensim optimizes the model using stochastic variational bayes. The model iteratively updates by merging statistics computed on subset of documents with the current model state. The final model may be sensitive to the initial model state. By default, gensim initializes these stats to 0, but in principle they could be set to something else.